# Password TextBox for Kendo UI MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm wanting to create a login page using the Telerik Kendo UI Textboxes so I will need my password input masked. Does anyone have any suggestions? I've tried:

```
                .TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "password" })
```

below is my code as pretty much standard it is:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
                .Name("password")
                .Placeholder("Password")
                .Label(label => label
                    .Content("Password")
                    .Floating(true)
                )
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%;border-radius: 7px;border-color: #ff4d41;" })
            )
```

Getting to the stage I'd be faster just creating my own textboxes lol

Comment: What is the problem with what you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per my understanding based on your question
you need to add `type="password"` in kendo UI control.

Like below code

```
 @(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
.Name("password")
.Placeholder("Password")
.Label(label => label
.Content("Password")
.Floating(true)
)
.HtmlAttributes(new {type="password", style = "width: 100%;border-radius: 7px;border-color: #ff4d41;" })
)
```

> Output
> [image]

As we know `Password` HTML helper available in MVC.

```
@Html.Password()
@Html.PasswordFor()
```

Comment: Welcome @BlairGibson :)